# Export to .csv from html

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I want to export a table in my html page to a .csv file. I can use something like:

```
private void GenerateExcelFileOnType(string filePath1, ref DataTable dt)
        {
            if (dt != null)
            {
                string line = string.Empty;
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string str = dt.ToCSV();
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath1))
                    {
                        sw.Write(str);
                    }
                }
                dt.Clear();
                dt = null;
            }
        }
```

But is there any way with which I can directly export from the html page, like we do a `print (windows.print)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's no reliable way of initiating a downloadable file straight from a web page, other than sending another HTTP Request and responding with a downloadable mime-type.

I can't really see a great need for one either. So long as you can send a request with the various information needed, your server can respond appropriately.

**Update**

It seems, from your comments, that you aren't looking to actually write to a CSV file locally. If you just want to display the CSV as text within the browser, then ***of course*** this is possible, with some simple iteration:

```
function csv(id){

  var output = '';

  $('table#' + id + ' tr').each(function(i){

    if(i)
      output += '</br>';

    var children = $(this).find('td, th');

    children.each(function(j){

      output += '\"' + $(this).html() +  '\"';

      if(j < children.length - 1)
        output += ', ';

    });
  });

  return output;

}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2uD/4/)...

Comment: Okay ,But can't I iterate through the rows of the table , and write them to a csv?

Comment: The short answer is no. You could iterate through a table and send the data to your server, build the CSV server-side, and then pass it back to the browser to download. But the browser doesn't allow you to *'write'* to a local file on the clients machine. That would be a significant security flaw.

Comment: Hey , I got something!   Have a look at this!                       http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php

Comment: But that doesn't *'write'* to a local file, that just prepares the CSV as a string. The user still needs to copy it and paste it into a text file. If this is what you needed then you've not been very explicit in your question. ***Of course*** it's possible to parse any form of data into a *string* in JavaScript...

Comment: Okay , This is not exactly what I needed , but I can use it. Thanks for your help ! I will be more explicit from the next time.

Comment: That works, but Can you incorporate , that the csv opens in a new page?

Comment: @UjjwalVaish you'll need to figure that one out yourself I'm afraid. A good place to start would be [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open).

Comment: Thanks , you were of great help! :D